# Keep data from previous row for new row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table something like this:

```
    VIN         Color  Tires      Mileage
    -------------------------------------
    (car's VIN) red    P235/70R15 32976
```

If I do body work and change the color, change the tires, or the mileage changes while testing a repair, I want to be able to keep all of the unchanged fields (color, tires) from the previous row while inserting the new row with the new mileage.

I need to keep the existing row.

How can I use PHP and MySQL to accomplish this?

Comment: why you inserting new row? just update the existing one with new data.

Comment: Ah! The obligatory "Why?" question. As I stated before, I need the previous rows for my records. They cannot be modified or destroyed.

Comment: The fastest solution is to SELECT the three fields into variables, update the variables you want to change, then INSERT a new row. But there are better ways - you might want to look at normalizing your database properly. I assume you've also got a date field somewhere in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a parent/child relationship.
Here's an example with required columns to work:

```
ID parent_id    VIN        Color   Tires        Mileage
-------------------------------------------------------
1  NULL         (car's vin) red    P235/70R15   32976
2  1            ''          blue   P235/70R15   35017
```

Notice you're establishing that `ID` 2 is a **child of** `ID` 1, with updated information.

You'll simply create a walker function to pull the relationships between parent and child

Comment: I think you misunderstood. There is no parent child relationship. The VIN is whatever the VIN of the car is. What I posted before is just an example to explain the situation. It's not my actual database structure. It's a simplified example to aid you in understanding my problem and in me understanding any solutions someone may come up with.

Comment: Maybe explain a bit better in your question? To me it seems like you're trying to establish a 'history' of work done to said vehicle

Comment: Parent/child is perfect for a history of work. You're still keeping the same data - VIN, etc, but you're referencing a relationship between entries. I'm pretty sure I understood your question, or at least a way to solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know if your answer is correct because I don't understand the answer the way you stated it.